# Basic Windows 7 php web server?

Tags: php, web, windows-7

I am developing some postcard kiosks, which the client want to be able to remote into and see the status of each machine, order history, etc.

Each kiosk will have a 3G connection, and I was thinking of having a simple, resource light, web server running on each to output these details.

Can anyone recommend a package to use? All I need is PHP, and it to be lightweight.

Comment: Why Windows? For a kiosk, Linux is more stable, especially when used by many untrusted users. Then I'd recommend Nginx with PHP. Though it is off topic here. Just install an SSH server and you have remote access. This all is a hell on Windows, though not impossible.

Comment: if you want to use win7 (i guess cause of 3g modem drivers?) the most simple is apache+php

Comment: A *lightweight* server on *Windows*? That's somewhat of an oxymoron...

Comment: Using a windows box at the moment as the performance of the AIR app is better, this may and probably will change on the production version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Apache and turn every unneeded service off to conserve resources. In my opinion I think your biggest issue will be the 3G and its connection speed for use, but that could be corrected if it ends up hindering the end user.

Apache+PHP, secure the server and turn off all unneeded processes/services.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think the connection speed will be too much of an issue as I will only be serving a little bit of text about the status of the system

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best static server with PHP support is NGINX. It works on different operation system including Windows. If you need to use databases, then Apache+PHP+MySQL is realy best, but for static system is better to use NGINX. NGINX is much easier to configure than Apache.

Comment: Cheers, it sounds good I just hope there is a lot of info on how to configure it as this is all new to me.

Comment: There are links on documentations, wiki and FAQ: http://nginx.org/ Also you can find many information with google's help

Answer (score -1):

There's a very basic WAMP Package available at http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html. I can't vouch for how reliable or secure it is, but I've used it in PHP development and havn't had any issues.